# Java. How do I make code more effectly, HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have started learn Java sometime ago, and now I have interesting quest from my teacher. I will be very grateful for everyone who can help me. And I don`t want to get directly answer for my question, I want to see way which help for me understand core.

This is fragment from my code.

Higher I have some text (String) which was convert to List.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList( text.split( " "));

Map<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
int uniqueWords = 0;     
for (String word: list){
    Integer count = hashMap.get(word);
    hashMap.put(word, count == null ? 1 : count + 1);
    if (count == null){
        uniqueWords++;
    }else if (count == 1){
        uniqueWords --;
    }
}
```

I need to do code more effective. I thinking several days and can`t prupose more effectly code. I need help )

Comment: Please spell out your requirements.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What do you mean exactly by making your code "more effective"? Did your teacher tell you what needs to change?

Comment: only one, to do more effective this code ) it is all

Comment: There's no particular sense in keeping an explicit running count of unique words, because that count will always be equal to the number of entries in the map, i.e its `size()`.

Comment: I must to do code - easier

Comment: I dont think there's easy way, but you can make it a good code by adding a null check for the list before the for loop, so that it becomes more of a generalized one! As @JohnBollinger pointed out you can use the size() and also you could replace the if() {} else if{} with ternary operators as you did above.

Comment: Guys you forgot about "count of each word appearance" actually stored in map.

Comment: There's also no advantage (for your purposes) to wrapping the result of `String.split()` in a `List`; you can iterate directly over the result, a `String[]`, instead.

Comment: You only need to "put" words into the hashMap when "count" == null, otherwise you only need to increment "count". (because "word" is already a key in the map). and the number of unique words in the map is always the number of words in the map's keySet().  But if you want the number of words in the keySet() that were not repeated in the input, you need to iterate the final hashmap and count the keys mapped to a value of 1.

Comment: @Vadim, "count of each word appearance" - is that really a requirement? It doesn't seem to be specified anywhere. To count unique words a Set must be sufficient.

Comment: John Bollinger. Some words used repeatedly and I must count their. Those words which used only one - is uniqe. How count words use smaller code?

Comment: @Mikhail Antonov. I do not care. It is in code and it is a purpose of Map there.

Comment: @Jhon Bollinger actually your answers is right ) tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are number of things just from "theoretical" glance:

1. You check value of count from map 3 times. You can do it only once
2. You can still use `if` statement(s) or you can use `switch` statement too
3. as @John Bollinger said String[] right out of split is enough.
4. Instead of using `hasMap.get(word)` first and check is `count == null` you can do `hashMap.containsKey(word)` first. It does not do much difference, just a matter of taste.

PS. There are more "exotic" ways with `List` like using `indexOf`, `lastIndexOf`, `subList`...

Comment: I believe that using `containskey()` first will harm performance because then if found you will need to call `get()` afterwards for one more lookup where one can do it. Now the question was about efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Set:

```
String text = "one two three one";
List<String> list = Arrays.asList( text.split( " "));

Set<String> uniqs = new HashSet<>();
uniqs.addAll(list);
System.out.println(uniqs.size()); // prints 3
```